# Razorpay flutter 1.1.4 Gradle build exception

Tags: flutter, dart, razorpay

In latest version of [razorpay_flutter 1.1.4](https://pub.dev/packages/razorpay_flutter#-readme-tab-) I have encountered a gradle exception could not open cp_proj remapped class cache for eii7mfeilb85f6s74q7cms80e.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in this unknown statement.

[image]

SOLUTION:

Go to `flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\razorpay_flutter-1.1.4\android`.

In `build.gradle` remove `package android` line and save.

Now this will work perfectly.